# Manually setting wordpress categories for fontface Icons

Tags: html, wordpress, themes, font-face, categories

I'm editing the twenty eleven theme but I want to change the categories so they display the icons as a @fontface icon instead of a word.

The categories needs to look something like this (using an art category as an example):

```
<a href="THELINKINHERE" rel="category" title="View all categories in Art"><i class="icon-brush"></i></a>
```

However this is how it currently looks.

```
<span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links">Posted in</span><a href="THELINKINHERE" rel="category" title="View all categories in Art">Art</a>
```

Here is what my code is at the moment:

```
<?php $show_sep = false; ?>
        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
        <?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) );
            if ( $categories_list ):
        ?>
        <span class="cat-links">
            <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', $categories_list );
            $show_sep = true; ?>
        </span>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif; // End if categories ?>
```

The  class needs to change depending on what post category is set is there a way to manually set what icon links to which category?

You can view my live template here http://mhutchinson.me.uk/
Thanks for your help!

Megan

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try something like this:

(change the printed HTML inside the foreach to fit your needs)

```
<?php 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
echo '<img src="http://example.com/images/' . $category->cat_ID . '.jpg" alt="' .    $category->cat_name . '" />'; 
} 
?>
```

Cheers